# npm error - "File or path name too long" during deployment of Laravel on Vapor on Windows 10

Tags: npm, laravel-vapor

I get the following error during deployment of Laravel on Vapor:

```
In Process.php line 256:
The command "npm ci && npm run prod && rm -rf node_modules" failed.
Exit Code: 1(General error)

rm: cannot remove `node_modules/.cache/terser-webpack-plugin/content-v2/sha512/d8/2c/[very long hash]': File or path name too long
```

I'm on Windows 10, and NPM 6.13.4.
It only happens when deploying to production. Deployment works fine to staging.

I have tried to activate long paths in Windows. That didn't work. 
On Vapor, I believe, that I have no way of changing Webpack configuration to use other paths or to flatten the `node_modules` folder. I have also looked through numerous answers regarding too long paths in NPM.

Do any of you have solutions or suggestions?